# How to display the current time?

Tags: windows-phone-7

How do I display the current time?  Please give me an example.

I know about [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev10.query?appId=Dev10IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k%28SYSTEM.DATETIME%29;k%28TargetFrameworkMoniker-%22SILVERLIGHT,VERSION=V4.0%22%29;k%28DevLang-CSHARP%29&rd=true) but still have a problem.

Comment: How do you want to display the time?

Comment: What are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: var timeLeft = DateTime.Now;

Clock.Text = String.Format("{0:D2}:{1:D2}:{2:D2}", timeLeft.Hours, timeLeft.Minutes, timeLeft.Seconds);

Comment: @JohnCE Try String.Format("{0:HH:mm:ss}", DateTime.Now);  Much clearer, simpler, and more useful.  http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/  You can also do DateTime.Now.ToString("HH:mm:ss"); http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zdtaw1bw.aspx

Comment: Please edit your question to add additional details—don't just put them in comments. The edit link is located right under the tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use by trying `DateTime.Now` to access the current time.